# The normal distribution - how to calculate the integral

Tags: probability

> Question: It was found that the mean length of $100$ parts produced by a
>   lathe was $20.05$ mm with a standard deviation of $0.02$ mm. Find the
>   probability that a part selected at random would have a length
>
> (a) between $20.03$ mm and $20.08$ mm.

The link for this question is here at example 5. http://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/14-normal-probability-distribution.php

So the solution is

$X$ = length of part
$0.03$ is $1$ standard deviation below the mean;

$20.08$ is $\frac{{{20.08}-{20.05}}}{{0.02}}={1.5}$ standard deviations above the mean.

$P(20.03 < X < 20.08)$

$ = P (-1 < Z < 1.5) $

$= 0.341 + 0.4332 $

$ = 0.7745$

So I need to compute
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-1}^{1.5}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx$$

But I am having trouble integrating this, I can only obtain the correct answer using an online integration calculator. How do I do this by hand?

Comment: Use a $Z$-table.

Comment: Basically, you don't: the integral has no closed-form antiderivative. What people normally do if they want such things is to look it up in tables: the exams I did at school would provide books of tabulated standard normal cumulative distribution functions for such purposes.

Comment: Your question has been asked often on this site.This well known integral can't be done using elementary tools. It's you can look up the numerical values in a table. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function.

Comment: Note that I had to make a substantial update. That table isn't conventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.intmath.com/counting-probability/z-table.php) is the table it references. Note that the table shows the area between $0$ and some number $a > 0$. (The format of the table is unconventional, in my opinion. Usually left-tailed or right-tailed - not from $0$ - areas are given. **It is important that you know what kind of $Z$-table you are looking at when using one.**) Note that $$P(-1 < Z < 1.5) = P(Z < 1.5) - P(Z < -1) = 1 - P(Z \geq 1.5) - [1-P(Z \geq -1)] = P(Z \geq -1)-P(Z \geq 1.5)$$
Draw a picture of the normal curve. Intuitively, the area in $[-1, \infty)$ should be equal to that of $(-\infty, 1]$ by symmetry. The area under the curve in $[0, 1]$ is $0.3413$ as shown in the table. The area in $(-\infty, 0)$ is $0.5$. So the area in $(-\infty, 1]$ is $0.5+0.3413=0.8413$.

The area in $[0, 1.5]$ is $0.4332$ (see table). The area in $[0, \infty)$ is $0.5$. So the area in $(1.5, \infty)$ is $0.5-0.4332 = 0.0668$.

Hence, the answer is given by $0.8413-0.0668=0.7745$.

For more traditional tables, the identity$$P(Z < -a) = 1 - P(Z<a)$$ is useful.